# equation for abelian varieties with a given polarization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, abelian-schemes

Let $A$ be an abelian variety of dimension g and a polarization $L$ of type $(d_1,.....,d_g)$ (let alone the case $d_i=d_j,$ $\forall i, j$). What is the degree of the generators of the homogeneous ideal of A projectively embedded via the sections of L?

I know that Gross and Popescu gave results for surfaces with L of type $(1,d)$ - for instance if $d>10$ the ideal is generated by quadrics - but what for other polarizations and most of all for higher dimensions? Is this known?

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't have enough details to really write it out here, you'll be wanting to look at Mumford's "On the Equations Defining Abelian Varieties [I](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/Papers/DigitizedAlgGeomPapers--ForNon-CommercialUse/66c--EqDefAVI.pdf), [II](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/Papers/DigitizedAlgGeomPapers--ForNon-CommercialUse/67a--EqDefAVII.pdf), [III](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/Papers/DigitizedAlgGeomPapers--ForNon-CommercialUse/67b--EqDefAVIII.pdf)", which are in volume I of his selected papers (as well as his website at the links provided), and also the wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_defining_abelian_varieties).